# MY_Model jamierumbelow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, my-model-jami

Guys

I have been using this model in my project.But ,nowadays i m facing with performance noises due to repeated query by with method and of course the need to make and Inner Join with Where clause on related objects  and how could i ever does that?

I have `Profile` ,`Media`,`Product` table related.
When i want to get all products with profile , media and details i use below code.And , its working except the with creates**repeated select statements.**

```
$all_products = $this->with('medias')->with('profile')->get_all();
```

**Now , i want all products their profile is verified.**

```
select * from products 
inner join profile as p on p.id = product.profile_id
inner join media as m on m.product_id=p.product_id 
where profile.is_verfied='true';
```

How can i ever do this using my MY_MODEL way or with little modifications.

Comment: Check if [this one](http://avenir.ro/revisiting-my_model-copying-jamie-rumbelow-looking-eloquent/) based on Jamie's one offers better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too use @Jamie Rumbelow's Base Model, with few modifications (one or two). When It comes to joining, it has a wonderful triggering method that you can use:  `before_get` observer. In your case, simply add an observer where you can join from needed tables like so:

In your model constructor:

```
public function __constrcutor()
{
    array_unshift(
        $this->before_get,
        'join_from_profile_and_media'
    );
    // Then
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And the observer would be:

```
protected function join_from_profile_and_media()
{
    $this->db->join('profile', 'profile.id = product.profile_id');
    $this->db->join('media', 'media.product_id = profile.product_id');
}
```

And now whenever you call `get()`, `get_many()`, `get_by()` or `get_many_by()` all tables are joint.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having performance issues, don't use `with()`! It's a crude way of managing relationships, only to be used for prototyping or simple relationships.

I'd recommend doing the joins manually:

```
$products = $this->select('products.*')
    ->join('profile', 'p.id = products.profile_id', 'inner')
    ->where('profile.is_verified', true)
    ->get_all();
```

Comment: You have built a great leverage.I like you My+Model , that is why i stick all this time with it. I feel like im in java or so.You know ORM is very easy to use. So , please only this thing can it be improved? Thanks!

Comment: : Call to undefined method Product_model::select()

Answer (score -1):

Danielad,

There are many caching technologies available. In my project, we are using [Redis](http://redis.io/), [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) as well. Also using client (Website) side caching for Javascripts, CSS, Images etc..

Redis/Memcached are very powerful tools. Facebook is using Memcached for very fast output and low load over database servers.

Hope this helps !!